# When running gitlab ci cd using using docker executor, is it important to have docker installed and running on the local system?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a basic question mentioned above. Why I am having this query us because when I am runninng CI/CD and when docker is not running on my local, then it shows me this error. May I know the answer for this? Also if it is not mandatory, can anybody please tell what should be the solution to fix this?

Error I get:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.4.0 (43b2dc3d)
on runner3-dockerlatest pbSCcuw5
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:09
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:863:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:863:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:863:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:863:0s)
```

Comment: You seem to have included a PNG file as part of the question.  How does your build system use or produce this image file, and how is it relevant to having Docker installed or not?  Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating a more specific problem?  Is your problem related to programming or deploying a CI tool?

Comment: @DavidMaze This question is related to Gitlab CI/CD as this is the error which I am getting in gitlab CI/CD console/termnial. I have made my gtilab-ci.yml file myself. When the docker is running on my local then this compiles perfectly, but when it is not running then shows this error. Why I am asking this question? I want to have confirmation do we really require docker to be running on local. If so, then why? Cause I am using docker executor. I read somewhere that we don't required docker on local to be running, but when it is not running, it is giving  this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your GitLab runner can't access to `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.
When you register runner as docker executer add this option `--docker-volumes='/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'`
Example:

```
gitlab-runner register \
--non-interactive \
--url "https://gitlab.com/" \
--registration-token "your_token" \
--executor "docker" \
--docker-image docker:20.10.20 \
--docker-tlsverify="false" \
--docker-privileged="false" \
--docker-volumes='/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock' \
--docker-volumes='/cache' \
--description "My runner" \
--tag-list "docker.sock,imac" \
--run-untagged="false" \
--locked="false" \
--access-level="not_protected"
```

If your runner in docker, don't forget mount `/var/run/docker.sock` from host into container:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```